# Jquery ajax response not calling Success method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am pretty much new to ajax and working on jquery ajax request. Ajax callback is not calling success method. Interaction is between cross-site domains.
My AJAX request looks like

```
   $.ajax({
       timeout: 20000,
       url: 'test.com',
       crossDomain: true,
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success: function (data) {
           console.log('callback success');
           this._cache = data;
           localStorage.token = data.access_token;
     } });
```

There are no errors in this call.

This ajax request is not calling success function.Request is returning json data. it's just success method is not getting called.

This ajax request is not calling success function.

Get request is getting fired successfully. I can even trace the response in fiddler with 200 http response.For some reason success method is not getting called.

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: You should also add method type: post or get. Whatkind of error do you get? Have you watched this request in browse onsole?

Comment: add `fail` function to it also, and check is the result step into that?

Comment: There is no erros w.r.t this request. It's just success method is not getting called

Comment: Add an error callback method as well and have a look, if it is called.

Comment: what happens if you manually go to the url? error? 404 etc?

Comment: "Request is responding properly" — What is it responding with? Your idea of "properly" might be wrong.

Comment: it's returning json object, which I've traced in fiddler

Comment: type jsonp never calls success callback. Set jsonp: 'success' as a setting if you want it to or implement jsonpCallback, what is called after a successful jsonp request. Or read jQuery documentation about what you are doing: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ jsonp is a special case.

Answer (score 1):

> it's returning json object, which I've traced in fiddler

You're telling jQuery to expect a JSONP response, so it is trying to execute the JSON document as if it were a JavaScript script (because that is what JSONP is). This fails because it is not JSONP.

Either return JSONP instead of JSON or (assuming the server returns the correct `Content-Type`) remove `dataType: 'jsonp',`.

Comment: I tried that with dataType:json but, that doesn't work in IE, though works in chrome and mozilla. That's the reason I've used jsonp as datatype

Comment: @rampuriyaaa — Well going from "working in Google and Firefox but not Microsoft" to "not working anywhere" seems like a step backwards. Specifying JSONP in the datatype only types if the data type really is JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

ok... I came here with the same problem... and when I read that specifying `datatype:jsonp` never calls success as a callback per @mondjunge from a comment above, it started me thinking about some behavior I saw earlier from my code and that maybe `datatype:json` might have the same behavior for what ever reason here too.

So after reading this page I took out my datatype declaration from my ajax request and my servlet returned the proper data payload, returned a 200, and jquery called the success function finally and modified my DOM.

All those steps happened except the last one until I removed my datatype from my ajax call.  NOT what I was expecting!

Hopefully someone else can shed some light on *why* this happens... for now at least the few that don't lose their minds to this issue that find this post can do this in the mean time.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if your ajax is executed
2. Check it's status. If response code is != 200, than you should add error method also, for error handling.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   timeout: 20000,
   url: 'test.com',
   method: 'GET',
   crossDomain: true,
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function (data) {
       console.log('callback success');
       this._cache = data;
       localStorage.token = data.access_token;
    }, 
    error: function(xhr, error){
       console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
    },
 });
```

Comment: It is not *missing* `type`, `type` is explicitly optional (and using JSONP forces it to GET anyway).